# Symfony2: default locale not translated in prod env

Tags: symfony, translation

I have set up my website translation on Symfony2 with JMSTranslationBundle and JMSI18nRoutingBundle. The default locale is "en", and I have successfully translated text to "fr".

In dev environment, everything is working great, I get the right translations in **/en** and **/fr** pages, but in prod environment, only **/fr** is correctly translated. In **/en** pages I only see the translations names, ie **text.submit**.

I'm using the **desc** filter as default translation, so I do not have xliff files for english.

Any idea what prevents the default translation from being used in **prod** environment?

Btw, I have cleared the cache ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the desc filter does not seem to be used in production, I had to create an english translation xliff file.

Comment: I too use this bundle - and only my /no translations were translated in production. This because production requires you to translate your keywords to all languages, even your default one /en